# RecyclerView & SnapHelper -> get snapped / targeted view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I very recently started using the `SnapHelper` provided inside the `Support Library v24` in order to have a nice horizontal `RecyclerView` much like in the **Google Play Store**.

My question is simple.

By using a `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener` I can be notified when the scroll state is **settling** (much like with `ViewPager.OnPageChangedListener`. This is important because when the scroll is settling, I need to animate the view that will be centered as the default behavior of the `LinearSnapHelper`. That animation shows that the **focus is brought to the soon-to-be centered item**.

For now, I managed to get the view that is centered when the scroll state is **idle** via the following line:

```
final int centered = (llm.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() - llm.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition())  / 2 + llm.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();  // where llm is my LinearLayoutManager
```

Problem is, starting the animation when the scroll is completed is weird: I really need to smoothly play the animation as the scroll is settling so that when the scroll is idle, the animation completes as well.

So as you can see, I have hard time finding out which item of my `RecyclerView` will be the one centered.

---

Here are the solutions I tried so far.

1. I tried using the same calculation when scroll state is set to `RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING`. Unfortunately, calling the `findVisiblePosition` methods from the adapter when the scroll isn't idle is a bad idea : depending on the scroll speed, the visible items, when these so-called methods are invoked, might not be exactly the same when the scroll is complete. Indeed it will tell me which items are visible at the time of the call. That makes total sense but I needed to try to find that out...
2. I tried **extending** the `LinearSnapHelper` so that when `onFling(...)` is called I can either use `findSnapView(...)` to get the view that will be **snapped** or use `findTargetSnapPosition(...)` hopefully telling me which view is to be centered when the scroll completes ;
3. I also tried, when scroll state is `RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING`, to use `findSnapView(...)`

Of all these solutions, none passed multiple tests (trying with different swipe strength & speed). Some got it right on a few occasions but got it wrong in different circumstances therefore rendering the solution unusable.

Having looked inside the `LinearSnapHelper` I think I started to understand that, somehow, after a swipe, this class computes the total scroll and snaps views on multiple occasions as long as necessary before the scroll completes (amount of distance to scroll) therefore knowing which view will be the **final snapped view** ... unless I got it all wrong because snapped is not centered?

Anyway, my main question is: **How can I know which item of my `RecyclerView` will be centered after a swipe, regardless of speed and strength of said swipe?**

Comment: Hey Mackovich can you please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49952965/recyclerview-horizontal-scrolling-to-left?noredirect=1#comment87836903_49952965

Answer (score 6):

Edit:

As a few have pointed out, this is not reliable, particularly when the snap occurs as the result of a slow swipe rather than a fling.

I'd recommend using a `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener`, and checking the position once the `RecyclerView` has 'settled'. There's a good tutorial on this here

https://medium.com/over-engineering/detecting-snap-changes-with-androids-recyclerview-snaphelper-9e9f5e95c424

---

Previous answer:

You need to subclass `SnapHelper` and override `findTargetSnapPosition`. The position calculated by `super.findTargetSnapPosition(layoutManager, velocityX, velocityY)` is the position your `RecyclerView` is about to snap to.

```
SnapHelper snapHelper = new LinearSnapHelper() {
    @Override
    public int findTargetSnapPosition(RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager, int velocityX, int velocityY) {
        int snapPosition = super.findTargetSnapPosition(layoutManager, velocityX, velocityY);

        // Do something with snapPosition

        return snapPosition;
    }
};
```

Comment: This is mostly not true. It often happens that when snapping `findTargetSnapPosition` returns -1.

Comment: This method is not reliable. It works only for fling. Also the base SnapHelper class uses this method in its OnFlingListener only

Comment: It returns -1 if the fling target distance is 0

Comment: @mradzinski in my case it was cause i was frequently updating list

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `LinearSnapHelper`, there is `LinearSnapHelper#findTargetSnapPosition` method. It returns the Adapter Position of the View to be snapped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()` when scrolling has settled.

Comment: Thank you but I was looking for a way to know which item will be centered **after** the swipe not when it has settled.

Answer (score 0):

I have a horizontal Recycler View , look at the layoutManager :

```
 val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true)

     val snapHelper: SnapHelper = PagerSnapHelper()
                snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
```

you can use findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition to find the position

```
 recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
                    val visiblePosition = layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
                    if (visiblePosition >= 0) {
                      //do somthing with item position
                  
                    }
                }
            })
```